# How to create custom routes on top of programmatically created pages in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to have programmatically created pages with dynamic routes on top of those but am running into an issue where it won't create the dynamic routes.

in my I gatsby-node.js have

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  {...graphql query}

  locations.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${edge.node.path}/details`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/detailsTemplate.js`),
      context: { name: edge.node.name }
    })
  })
}

exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  if (page.path.match(/^(.*?)\/details/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/details/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

my gatsby-config.js is:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
      options: { prefixes: [`/details/*`] },
    },
```

I am then using reach router to create routes of:
:location/details/faq
:location/details/contact
etc...

however it is not matching the routes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to pass variables (your dynamic routes) into a generated page is via [context](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages).

You need to set your routes inside your `exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {...}` in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  createPage({
    path: node.fields.slug,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/yourTemplate.js`),

    // ## PASS YOUR ROUTES HERE ##

    context: {
      faq: `faq/route`,
      contact: `contact/route`,
      etc: `etc/route`,
    },
  })
}
```

Then set your routes inside `yourTemplate.js`:

```js
const Article = ({ pageContext }) => {

  // Your routes are inside the pageContext prop
  console.log(pageContext.faq)
  // ...
}
```

This [article](https://dev.to/prvnbist/link-prev-next-articles-dynamically-on-your-gatsby-blog-49n9) discusses a similar use case and problem to yours.

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely overcomplicating things